# sublime plugin. show find-panel and paste text

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I need to get string from clipboard, then make with it some manipulations, run default find-panel and paste the string into this.

```
class ExampleCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        s = sublime.get_clipboard()
        try:
            s = s[:s.index('\n')]
        except:
            pass
        self.view.run_command('show_panel', *args* )
        self.view.run_command('paste')
```

In *args* I tried various interpretations of writing this snippet:

```
"args": {"panel": "find", "reverse": false} },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `show_panel` command is a WindowCommand, so it can't be executed using `view.run_command`.

Instead, you must use the window reference:

```
window.run_command('show_panel', { 'panel': 'find' })
```

i.e. to get the window from your view:

```
self.view.window().run_command('show_panel')
```

---

The arguments parameter needs to be a dictionary of arguments.

```
args = dict()
args['panel'] = 'find'
```

or

```
args = {"panel": "find", "reverse": False}
```

---

```
self.view.window().run_command('show_panel', args)
```

Comment: Yes! It's perfectly working. Thank you! (false -> False)